# What kind of distributions are the following

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $Y_1, . . . , Y_5$ be a random sample of size 5 from a normal population with mean 0 and variance 1 and let $\bar{Y} = (1/5) \Sigma_{i=1}^5 Y_i$

Let $Y_6$ be another independent observation from
the same population. Finally, let $U = \Sigma_{i=1}^5 (Y_i - \bar{Y})^2$ and let $W = \Sigma_{i=1}^5 Y_i^2 $.

What is the distribution of

a. $\frac{\sqrt{5} * Y_6}{\sqrt{W}} $

b. $\frac{2 * Y_6}{\sqrt{U}} $

c. $\frac{2*(5\bar{Y}^2 + Y_6^2)}{U} $

Why?

I don't really get how to examine the problems. Maybe if I understood the answer to a. I could understand the other 2 but I don't have an answer to any of them right now.

Edit:
The distributions are probably either
T distribution
Chi distribution
normal
but it could be something else I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the known distributions

a.

It's a Student's T with 5 d.o.f.

$$\frac{Y_6}{\sqrt{\frac{W}{5}}}\sim\mathcal{T}_5$$

This because $Y_6\sim\Phi$, $W\sim \chi_{(5)}^2$ and $Y_6\perp\!\!\!\perp W$

If you got a. the rest of the exercise follows as a consequence.

b. The distribution is

$$\frac{Y_6}{\sqrt{\frac{U}{4}}}\sim\mathcal{T}_4$$

I just did a copy & paste

c. Try yourself first...it's a Fischer distribution: $F(2;4)$

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing $T_4$ and $T_5$?
Also yeah this helps I think im getting it now.
Ill try C. I assume its a T distribution but ill see if I can piece it together

Comment: Ok so I tried distribution the 5 and seperating the fractions

$(10 * \bar{Y}^2)/ U    + 2 * Y_6^2  / U$

I can see how the part on the right is a T distribution i think? but I'm not sure about the left because it's $\bar{Y}$ rather than $Y_6$

Comment: @RandomGuy57 c is a little bit more complicated, it is a ratio of 2 independent $\chi^2$ divided by their d.o.f....  I would like you to try yourself...It is a very good way to learn...otherwise I can get you the solution...as you prefer

Comment: I'm honestly really struggling to get it. I'm looking at lecture notes to try and get it but I'm really lost. I would appreciate if you could show me the solution

Answer (score 0):

Let's see our components:

- $$U=\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2}\sim\chi_{(4)}^2$$
- $$Y_6\sim N(0;1)$$

Obviously $Y_6^2\sim \chi_{(1)}^2$

- $$\overline{Y}\sim N\left(0;\frac{1}{5}\right)$$

That is

$$\sqrt{5}\cdot\overline{Y}\sim N(0;1)$$

and obviuosly

$$5\overline{Y}^2\sim\chi_{(1)}^2$$

Thus

$$V=5\overline{Y}^2+Y_6^2\sim\chi_{(2)}^2$$

Being in a gaussian model $V\perp\!\!\!\!\!\!\perp U$ your distribution is

$$\frac{\frac{V}{2}}{\frac{U}{4}}\sim F(2;4)$$